# Deleting char matrix

Tags: c++, char, delete-operator

I'm having trouble deleting a char matrix ,
I'm using visual studio and I'm getting an error once the code reaches this line :

```
delete[] AlloBoard[i];
```

this is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char** buildMat(int h, int w)
{
    char**mat;
    mat = new char*[w];
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        mat[i] = new char[h];
    return mat;
}
int main()
{
    char** AlloBoard=buildMat(4,5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            AlloBoard[i][j] = 'x';
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            cout << AlloBoard[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        delete[] AlloBoard[i];
            delete[] AlloBoard;

            cout << "DONE" << endl;
}
```

appreciate the help!

Comment: Now would be an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger and development tools, such as static memory sanitizing tools like `valgrind`. A straight pass of the shown code through `valgrind` pointed out where the memory corruption originates. Investing a little bit of time learning how to use tools that all C++ developers must know how to use means that you will be able find and fix your bugs all by yourself, instead of running to stackoverflow.com every time your program doesn't work. One part of the shown code thinks the matrix is 4x5, the rest 5x4, resulting in corruption.

Comment: I changed the for loop for i<4 its still crashes, so I dont undestand my error

Comment: Print out: 1) the size of the first dimension that's allocated. 2) the size of each second dimension that gets allocated. 3) ***Everywhere*** the matrix gets accessed, the first dimension's index and the 2nd dimension's index. This will tell you where your bug is.

Comment: `buildMat` has the `h` and `w` parameters in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initially create 5 arrays of 4 chars each, but then you treat it like 4 arrays of 5 chars each. If your intent is to have matrix like this:

```
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
```

You need to change

```
buildMat(4,5);
```

to

```
buildMat(5,4);
```

And when deleting, do the loop to 4 not 5

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    delete[] AlloBoard[i];
        delete[] AlloBoard;
```

https://ideone.com/4cgCt3